# CSS: Select element that comes before another

Tags: css

How to select `.container` that comes before `.before_display_none`?

```
<div class="container">...</div>
<div class="before_display_none"></div>
```

I found only element + after element{}.

Comment: You don't have a previous selector in CSS. Only adjacent and sibling selectors. So, from my point of view, not possible.

Comment: @OriDrori OKay... `:)`

Comment: @Sevi - in the answer [Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector) look for the flexbox solution.